# JQuery showing an image within an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need a little help positioning a div correctly.

This is my code:

```html
<td width="318" height="450" align="left" style="border:solid 1px #666;">
    <div id="foldLeft" style="position:relative; top:0px; left:0px; z-index:1001;">
        <img src="foldLeft.png">
    </div>
    <div id="leftPage">
        <img src="page2.jpg">
    </div>
</td>
```

I have a button, onMouseOver it should show the DIV element called `foldLeft`, which was hidden on page load, in the top-left corner of that TD. This works fine but the DIV should be on top of everything, instead it's pushing the content down 30 pixels (the size of the DIV).

How can I position this so it sits at the top-left corner of the TD but is on top of everything? I thought z-index would sort that out but hasn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<td width="318" height="450" align="left" style="border:solid 1px #666; position:relative">
<div id="foldLeft" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; z-index:1001;"><img src="foldLeft.png"></div>
<div id="leftPage"><img src="page2.jpg"></div>
</td>
```

Comment: but then the DIV appears top left of the screen, not top left of the element

Comment: have you added `position: relative` to the `<td>` ?

Comment: chanhe to `<td width="318" height="450" align="left" style="border:solid 1px #666; position:relative; display: block">`   - http://jsfiddle.net/Xjpyv/

Comment: Perfect thanks. Had to change to inline-block as I had 2 table cells next to each other. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score -1):

You should use position:absolute;  instead of position:relative;

Like this:

```
 div_name{
 position:absolute;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 }
```

Or

```
<div id="foldLeft" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;"> </div>
```

Comment: but then the DIV appears top left of the screen, not top left of the element

Comment: Why was this -1 by you? if the element is positioned relative ot will be in the top left of the element